# Which CSS pre processor is better and most used: SASS or LESS?

Tags: css, web-development, less, frontend

Before someone may asks, I searched for questions about this but didn't find anything close to that subject. Additionally, if my question is in the wrong place, please let me know and point the correct Stack network to post it.

I need to learn some pre processors because I've passed a long time working just with backend (actually I'm a web designer and not developer) but now I'm seeking for jobs in US (I'm from Sao Paulo) and today any job seeker needs to have some pre processors to work with front-end and design staff in US, that's a must and very required. Then, before get start using one or other, I'd like to know from you, front-end professionals, what's your opinion about that question and which one you have been using for your projects. In addition, I need to know which one fits better or has a better integration with Dreamweaver CC.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no single answer but, in my opinion, you should choose based on what your *dependencies* use.

For example, with *Bootstrap 4*, the team are moving to *SASS*. If you use *SASS*, you can include their *SASS* sources instead of serving the pre-made Bootstrap 4 `.css` files - this gives you all sorts of power to override variables that affect Bootstrap or to pick and choose parts of Bootstrap to include or to `@extend` Bootstrap classes in your own CSS rules.

With respect to your question about Dreamweaver integration: *never* pick your tech. based on your tools. Pick your tools to work with the tech. you judge to be best.

Comment: Good, I already had thought about that. Thanks for helping, your answer was great, I will pick SASS, bootstrap has been a must nowadays! I asked about Dreamweaver because it has been the base tool of my work, but you're absolutely right, I can pick technologies based on tools. Let me ask you something else: Does .scss extension come from SASS or LESS? I appreciate your help!